# Error with reference to an external library in a wcf-ria service class library with IIS 7.5 on Windows-7 64 bit

Tags: iis, dll, silverlight-4.0, iis-7, wcf-ria-services

To create my Silverlight 4.0 Application I have started from the template "Business Application" in Visual Studio 2010. Then I have added a project WCF-RIA Class Library and I have referenced it in the main ASP.Net project. Then in the project WCF-RIA I have added the reference to a external .DLL created by a my collaborator, from which I get the data.

The problem is this: while I execute my application with Visual Studio Development Server (Cassini) everything is allright. When I try to execute the application on IIS (Ver. 7.5 on my Windows-7 64 Bit) I get an error caused by the reference to the external .DLL (infact if I remove the .DLL everything works again).

My application must be configured as it is, then I ask: what is the problem, and (specially) how can I work it around?

Thank you very much in advance!

Pileggi

This is the Error:

Server Error in '/MyApp' Application.

---

Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibrary' or one of its dependencies. Tentativo di caricare un programma con un formato non corretto.
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibrary' or one of its dependencies. Tentativo di caricare un programma con un formato non corretto.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MyLibrary' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
 To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
 Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
 To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibrary' or one of its dependencies. Tentativo di caricare un programma con un formato non corretto.]
    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +567
    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +192
    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +147

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibrary' or one of its dependencies. Tentativo di caricare un programma con un formato non corretto.]
    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +1298
    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +430
    System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +104
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +334
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +264
    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1021

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibrary' or one of its dependencies. Tentativo di caricare un programma con un formato non corretto.]
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +646
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +771

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found, the problem is that the DLL is built for 32 bit systems and IIS, by default, allows only files built for the same cpu of the operating system (and my is a 64 bit). To solve, 2 options: re-build the DLL for 64 bit cpu or change the property "Allows 32 bit applications" of the Application Pool.